# How can I do this formatting in a double

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, .net-core

I'm a doubt when formatting a number of type double.

I would like it to be from `250000.0` to `250.000`

With **dot** and not comma

Another example: from `26000` to `26.000`

Comment: What is expected output for value `250000.99`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [The Numeric ("N") Format Specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#NFormatString).
To force specific thousands separator, specify NumberGroupSeparator.

```
var num = 250000.0;
NumberFormatInfo nfi = new CultureInfo( "en-US", false ).NumberFormat;
nfi.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
var numString = num.ToString("N0", nfi);
```

Comment: When I run that I get `250,000`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var value = 250000.0;
var text = value.ToString("N0", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"));
```

This gives `250.000` as you asked.

You can simply replace the culture code, `"de-DE"`, with one that gives you the output you need.